# How to trace linked lists to determine resulting list?

Tags: python, list

I'm confused as to how exactly to trace linked lists to figure out what the output would be.

For example, if a linked list was like:

Head --> 17 --> 42 --> 25 --> 32 --> 6 --> None

And this was the code that went with it:

```
NewNode = {} 
newNode[‘data’] = Head[‘data’] 
newNode[‘next’] = None 
ptr = Head 
count = 0 
while count < 3 and ptr != None:  
   ptr = ptr[‘next’] 
   count = count + 1 
if ptr != None: 
   newNode[‘next’] = ptr[‘next’] 
   ptr[‘next’] = newNod
```

and

```
ptr = Head 
while ptr[‘data’]  != 25: 
   ptr[‘data’] = 0 
   ptr = ptr[‘next’]
```

I'm confused as to how one would go about showing the resulting list. I understand that ['data'] is the value, ['next'] is a placeholder for the value after, and etc. But how do you determine the resulting list?

How would your approach change if it were doubly-linked?

Also, optional bonus Q just for my own general knowledge: why would you use a linked list? They seem pretty pointless to me at the moment, but maybe I'm just missing something.

Comment: Python lists happen to be variable-length arrays, but they could be linked lists (it would change their performance). You're learning the fundamental data structures that we build nearly everything useful from. They can seem very trivial in Python because Python already has a lot of nice things built into it. If you find yourself in a C environment, however, you'll find yourself using things like linked lists often.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm confused as to how one would go about showing the resulting list

Like this:

```
node = Head
while node:
    print (node['data'])
    node = node['next']
```